# Autostart VNC server in Knoppix

Tags: linux, boot, vnc, knoppix

How can I autostart my VNC server on my Knoppix installation?

Comment: What are you running Knoppix from? A liveCD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a file called `~/.config/autostart/xvnc.desktop`.

Place within it this text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XVNC Server
Exec=/usr/local/bin/xvnc.sh
Icon=
Type=Application
```

---

Now `su` to root and do the following.

Create a file called `/usr/local/bin/xvnc.sh` and place within it the following text:

```
#!/bin/bash
xhost +
x11vnc -display :0 -forever -passwd "foobar" &
```

And run `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xvnc/sh`.

Exit from root.

---

This will allow connections as long as the server is running, and access to be granted by the password "foobar" as LXDE is started.

Comment: mmm... the problem is .xinitrc doesn't exists...!

Comment: @stighy What's your window manager? I may be able to pinpoint your WM's startup file for you.

Comment: My window manager is Lxde